# html css span hover not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I am using a span hover as below and works on IE and Opera but not Firefox. The very strange thing is that it does work on my local machine in Firefox but after I host my website it works on the real live site in every browser except Firefox...

css file ....

```
span.dropt:hover {text-decoration: none;  z-index:6; ;width: 19%;}
span.dropt span {position: absolute; right: -9999px;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:0px; z-index:6;}
span.dropt:hover span {right: 2%;}
```

html ...

```
          <tr>
            <td style="width:290px;"><p style="font-family:Chalk; colour:white; font-size:x-large;"><b><u>Learn to draw: </u><br />
            Great drawing course
            </b></p></td>
            <td style="width:400px;"><p style="font-family:verdana;"></p><b>Move beyond crayons
            </b></td>
            <td style="width:180px;"><p style="font-family:verdana;"></p><b><span class="dropt"><p style="font-family:verdana; text-align:center;">Basic Drawing</p><span><img src="MyFolder\ImageToPopUpOnHover.png"/><br/></span></span></b></td>
            <td style="width:125px;"><b>Over 12s

            </b></td>
          </tr>
```

How can I make this work in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is incorrect. You are using `.span` instead of `span` as a selector. It should be:

```
span.dropt:hover {text-decoration: none;  z-index:6; ;width: 19%;}
span.dropt span {position: absolute; right: -9999px;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:0px; z-index:6;}
span.dropt:hover span {right: 2%;}
```

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I had tried both out of desperation. Actually the span does have the problem that I described though. Sorry for my misleading question, I have updated it to be clearer ...

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to Steve Sanders' answer, here is something you need to fix:   `span.dropt:hover {text-decoration: none;  z-index:6; ;width: 19%;}`  has an extra semicolon after z-index.

This is correct:

```
span.dropt:hover {text-decoration: none; z-index:6; width: 19%;}
```

Comment: That's true but removing the extra semi-colon doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.